# Set mnemonic key button programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to change the text of the `Button` but also add the mnemonic key.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     button3.UseMnemonic = true;
    button3.Text = "&foo";
}
```

What I want to get:

[image]

What I get right now:

[image]

Comment: You could refer to this question on SuperUser: https://superuser.com/questions/16952/how-to-enable-underscore-shortcut-mnemonics-for-menu-items

Comment: You usually have to hit the ALT key to get it to display, it's a hot-key you're making.  So hitting ALT should show the underline, and ALT+[thekey] activates it.